# How to repeat a Function and store values in R using the function sim.msm

Tags: r, for-loop, storage, simulation, repeat

I would like to simulate 10000 result for  the function  below and store the values.It is a function available on the package msm (R-software).

```
sim.msm(qmatrix,15)
Result:

$states
[1] 1 2 3 2 3 2 2

$times
[1]  0.000000  1.538988  2.240587  9.695302 11.002184 14.998754 15.000000

$qmatrix
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] -0.11  0.10  0.01
[2,]  0.05 -0.15  0.10
[3,]  0.02  0.07 -0.09
```

This is only one simulation . I need 10000 like this.

Grateful if someone could help me

Answer (score 0):

Replicate allows to repeat N times the same command. Here N = 10 :

```
replicate(10, sim.msm(qmatrix,15), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: However I am  still struggling to aggregate all these results in a single list.I want columns containing  the id ,the changes in states and their corresponding time.I have been struggling with storage function but in vain .

Comment: Result is already a list. The id is the position in the result which is a list. You can assess it with `result[[position_id]]` with position_id from 1 to 10000 here.